# How to insert a title of the presentation into a light LightCyan color box?

Tags: beamer, color, presentations

Can you please help me to insert the title of the presentation - "Title ABC" into a LightCyan color box?

Below I attach the code that I use:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{
\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{default}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber, natbib]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
 andothers = {et al.},
}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma,compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue, linkcolor=white}


\newcommand{\MYhref}[3][blue]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}%

\title[Mock Presentation, UC3M]{Title ABC}

\author[ABC] { ABC \\}

\institute[AUMM]{XYZ \\ }

\date{October, 2019}




\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=LightCyan}` should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of `\setbeamercolor{title}` you can achieve the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=LightCyan}

\title[Mock Presentation, UC3M]{Title ABC}
\author[ABC]{ABC}
\institute[AUMM]{XYZ}
\date{October, 2019}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```